# Javascript getter / setter with an array: how can I automatically set a property based on the array item index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, getter-setter

Let’s say I have a `playlist` class like this one:

```
class playlist{
  constructor(urls){
      this.tracks=urls;
  }
}
```

I want to use a [javascript setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) to create an array of `track` objects based on the urls input.

```
class track{
  constructor(url,num){
      this.url=url;
      this.num = num;
  }
}

class playlist{

  constructor(urls){
      this.tracks=urls;
  }

  //tracks setter
  set tracks(urls){
      this.tracks = urls.map(function(url,index) {
          return new track(url,index+1);
      })
  }
}
```

This is fine.
But if I remove some items of the *tracks* array of the `playlist` object, if I slice it, etc;  the *num* properties of the `track` objects will not « update » : I want their *num* property **to be always the track index+1**.

Is it possible to automate this and how?

**EDIT**
The idea behind those classes is to extend standardized [JSPF](https://xspf.org/jspf) objects, in the goal of having `{...playlistdata}` or `{...trackdata}` output a regular JSPF object - the code above has been simplified for the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of a setter make a getter that returns a mapped array.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What if the same `track` is in different `playlist` objects, with different indexes?

Comment: if num is number of tracks in the playlist then num should be a property on playlist. you should update it when setting the tracks

Comment: @AlimÖncül IIUC, it's the index of the track in the playlist.

Comment: @Barmar: that doesn’t happen in my code.  The idea of having that class is to extend a standardized data structure object ([JSPF tracks](https://xspf.org/jspf ))with custom methods.

Comment: you need to implement your own method in the `playlist` class to remove tracks. Then it can update the `num` attributes of all the following tracks.